# Create Workbooks from Worksheets with Dynamic Auto-Adjusting VBA Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several sheets containing hundreds of price grids that need to be split into individual workbooks (one price grid per workbook). The level of VBA required here largely exceeds my basic knowledge of the subject and I would greatly appreciate any help you are willing to give.

Each worksheet has a number of these grids of varying sizes separated by a blank row and a blank column:

```
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Product1 |      |  100 |  200 | 300  |  400 |
| Product2 |  600 |  862 |  976 | 1024 | 1456 |
| Product3 |  800 |  975 | 1076 | 1156 | 1287 |
| Product4 | 1000 | 1076 | 1187 | 1245 | 1867 |
|          | 1200 | 1187 | 1294 | 1354 |      |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I need to make one Excel file/workbook per product. The name of each workbook will be the product name from column A and the contents must be the full grid without column A, so just all the numbers. Each workbook can be saved in ActiveWorkbook.Path. The given example would generate 4 files named Product1, Product2, Product3 and Product4. Each file would contain only the pricing grid starting in cell A1, which as shown in the example is sometimes empty.

The following code selects each price grid block on the worksheet but then I am unsure how to loop through the data to extract the product names. "Sheet1" and "A1" in this example would also need to be dynamic values, something that would loop through all sheets and find all the blocks on each sheet.

```
Sub DynamicRange()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")

StartCell.CurrentRegion.Select

End Sub
```

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

The solution will depend on how the data is separated. Your example is not clear.

You say the data is separated by one blank row and one blank column. Which is it?

You also say that you want the workbook to be named Product1,Product2 etc, but in your example the last row is blank. Workbooks can't have blanks names.

Here's some code to loop through the worksheets and output a workbook, assuming you can select the range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub loopThroughSheets()
    Dim ws  As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ' ... some loop to select ranges here ...
            Call outputRange(rng)
    Next ws

End Sub

Sub outputRange(rng As Range)
    Dim wb      As Workbook
    Dim arry()  As Variant
    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim j       As Integer
    Dim wbName  As String
    arry = rng'assigns range values to variant array

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 1 To UBound(arry, 1)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        wbName = arry(i, 1)
        For j = 2 To UBound(arry, 2)
            wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, j - 1) = arry(i, j)
        Next j
        Wk.SaveAs Filename:=(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & wb.name & ".xlsx")
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply Daniel. Yes, to clarify, the data is separated by a blank row.

Comment: What I am struggling with, is indeed, selecting the range.  In the example data there are only 4 products to which that pricing grid applies, so when we get to the blank row we must stop creating workbooks for that particular grid and select the next grid which will be after the next blank row or on the next sheet. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: The output would be 4 files that look like this                                           +--------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
|           |  100  |  200   |   300  |    400  |
|  600   |  862  |   976  |  1024 |  1456  |
|  800   |  975  |  1076 |  1156 |  1287  |
| 1000  | 1076 | 1187  |  1245 |  1867  |
|  1200 | 1187 | 1294  |  1354 |            |
+--------+-------+--------+---------+--------+

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you, looks like you've got it sorted though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel... I got it working.

`Sub ExtractGridsMS()`

```
Dim wbAllProducts As Workbook
Dim wsAllProducts As Worksheet

Set wbAllProducts = ThisWorkbook

For Each wsAllProducts In wbAllProducts.Sheets
    MkDir wbAllProducts.Path & "\" & wsAllProducts.Name
    For Each it In wsAllProducts.Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
    With Workbooks.Add
        it.CurrentRegion.Offset(, 1).Copy .Sheets(1).Cells(1)
        .SaveAs wbAllProducts.Path & Application.PathSeparator & wsAllProducts.Name & Application.PathSeparator & it.Value & ".xls", xlExcel8
        .Close 0
    End With
    Next it
ChDir ".\.."
Next wsAllProducts
```

End Sub